# VSCode Java Language Server not detecting artifacts (present, but unavailable) in pom.xml, but Maven still compiling

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode's remote ssh to develop on an amazon EC2 instance, as the GUI on the remote machine is horribly slow. Additionally, I'm using Atlassian's plugin SDK, which comes with it's own version of Maven. Maven can package the project fine on the host and remote computer, and the language server can detect the project just fine on the host computer. However, when I use VSCode's remote ssh tool to open the project on my remote computer, the Java Language Server gives these errors.

> Error occured while building workspace. Details:
> message: Project build error: Unknown packaging: atlassian-plugin; code: 0; resource: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/Dev/ResearchPlugin/CSVServerTestPlugin/pom.xml; line: 19
> message: Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:8.1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:jar:8.1.2 (present, but unavailable): com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:jar:8.1.2 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced; code: 0; resource: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/Dev/ResearchPlugin/CSVServerTestPlugin/pom.xml; line: 1
> message: Missing artifact com.atlassian.jira:jira-api:jar:7.13.0; code: 0; resource: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/Dev/ResearchPlugin/CSVServerTestPlugin/pom.xml; line: 22
> message: Missing artifact com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig:jar:0.2.0; code: 0; resource: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/Dev/ResearchPlugin/CSVServerTestPlugin/pom.xml; line: 45
> message: Missing artifact com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner:jar:2.0.2; code: 0; resource: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/Dev/ResearchPlugin/CSVServerTestPlugin/pom.xml; line: 71
> message: Missing artifact com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2-atlassian-1; code: 0; resource: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/Dev/ResearchPlugin/CSVServerTestPlugin/pom.xml; line: 83

However, the Maven for Java extension can detect all dependencies just fine with this settings.json file:

```
{
    "java.configuration.maven.globalSettings": "/usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.8/apache-maven-3.5.4/conf",
    "maven.executable.path": "/usr/bin/atlas-mvn",
    "java.maven.downloadSources": true,
    "java.help.collectErrorLog": true,
    "java.import.maven.offline.enabled": false,
    "java.maven.updateSnapshots": true,
    "java.server.launchMode": "Standard",
    "java.trace.server": "messages",
}
```

I'm not sure why the Maven extension works while the Java Language Server doesn't, am I missing some config settings to point to the Maven config file? I don't have any other version of Maven installed, and atlas-mvn -version returns `Apache Maven 3.5.4`.

Here's the pom.xml file in case that's useful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"\>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TESTING</groupId>
    <artifactId>CSVServerTestPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>
    
    <name>CSVServerTestPlugin</name>
    <description>This is the TESTING:CSVServerTestPlugin plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>${osgi.javaconfig.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OSGi Java Config dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
    
                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
    
                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>
                            TESTING.api,
                        </Export-Package>
    
                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                            org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
    
                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.13.0</jira.version>
        <amps.version>8.1.2</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.2</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <osgi.javaconfig.version>0.2.0</osgi.javaconfig.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project\>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps

1. Add the following in *settings.json*:

   ```json
       "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
           "lib/**/*.jar"
       ]
   ```

   *Make sure to add the actual location of the JAR*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`
3. Restart vscode

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I added both the path with wildcards to the jars in the .m2 maven folder and the individual path to each .jar, and neither worked.

Comment: What if instead of the vscode button I use the maven command in the terminal?

Comment: If you mean the maven run command, that does work. My issue is that there is no syntax highlighting or method previews or anything of the sort, which is especially troublesome with large maven repositories.